# Python - Clustering neighborhood pixels

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I am looking for a clustering algorithm, preferably in python, that clusters all pixels which are located directly next to each other.

So for example, in the picture below, I would get 4 Clusters as an output. (Each color represents a cluster)

[image]

Comment: What's the significance of the black lines please?

Comment: The black lines are the boundaries for the pixel.

Answer (score 0):

Could you be more precise?

I think that normally any clustering would do (some are better at recognizing this shapes of clusters, other the other one), but the problem normally is to determine how many clusters do you need to search.

If for example in the picture you reference one would set that we only search for 3 clusters normally the green one would be either yellow or red (depending of the distance calculations and clustering algorithm).

Do you really search clustering algorithm or just heuristic solution to flag each "cluster" with different color? This would be just unconnected graph components if the given matrix define edges between nodes.

Comment: Clustering is probably not the right term for my problem. I am looking for an algorithm, where I apply something like Breadth-first search for each pixel. As an output, I would generate several trees and each tree would be my "cluster".

Comment: So you could have a tree which is not binary? How would you like your output to be, for instance for red cluster in the attached image?

Answer (score 0):

```
points_np=([[1, 0],
   [2, 0],
   [5, 0],
   [6, 0],
   [7, 0],
   [0, 1],
   [2, 1],
   [3, 1],
   [6, 1],
   [2, 2],
   [3, 2],
   [1, 3],
   [2, 3],
   [3, 3],
   [3, 4]]) 

points_np= np.asarray(points_np)

from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

def get_labels_of_dbscan(points_np):
    clustering= DBSCAN(eps=1.5, min_samples=1).fit(points_np)
    labels= clustering.labels_
    print("number of clusters:",len(set(labels)))
    plt.figure();
    plt.scatter(points_np[:,0],points_np[:,1], c= labels)
    plt.show()
    return labels
```

I found a solution with the help of DBScan from the sklearn library. If you set 1.5 for the epsilon parameter and min_samples=1 you get exactly the result I was looking for.

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rdo2Y.png)